# I'm having an issue with my Purge command (Discord.js)

Tags: javascript, discord.js

When I use the command, if there are messages older than 14 days and there are a few messages not older than 14 days, I'm able to delete those messages not older than 14 days, but still get the 14 days error. I want it to return the error only if there are 0 messages not older than 14 days.
Please help.

My code:

File name: purge.js

```
module.exports = {
    
        name: "purge",
        aliases: ['clear'],
        category: "moderation",
        permissions: "MANAGE_MESSAGES",
        description: "Deletes messages from a channel.",
        usage: "purge [amount of messages] [ignore pinned messages]",
  
    execute: async (message, args) => {
        if (!message.member.hasPermission("MANAGE_MESSAGES")) return message.channel.send("You don't have enough perms! You require: [MANAGE_MESSAGES]")

        message.delete()
        if (!args[0]) {
            message.channel.bulkDelete(100)
          .then().catch(e => {
            message.channel.send(e.message)
              })
            .then(messages => message.channel.send(`**Succesfully deleted ${messages.size - 1} messages**`).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))).catch(() => null)
            return
          
        }
        else if (args[0] === "true") {
          
        const fetched = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 100 });
        const notPinned = fetched.filter(fetchedMsg => !fetchedMsg.pinned);

        await message.channel.bulkDelete(notPinned)
            .then().catch(e => {
            message.channel.send(e.message)
              })
            .then(messages => message.channel.send(`**Succesfully deleted ${messages.size - 1} messages.**`).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))).catch(() => null)
            return
        
      }

        
            

        else if (parseInt(args[0]) > 100) {
            return message.channel.send("**Please Supply A Number Less Than 100!**");
        }

        else if (parseInt(args[0]) < 1) {
            return message.channel.send("**Please Supply A Number More Than 1!**");
        }
        if (args[1] === "true") {
          
          const fetched = await message.channel.messages.fetch({ limit: args[0] });
          const notPinned = fetched.filter(fetchedMsg => !fetchedMsg.pinned);

          await message.channel.bulkDelete(notPinned)
            .then().catch(e => {
            message.channel.send(e.message)
              })
            .then(messages => message.channel.send(`**Succesfully deleted ${messages.size - 1} messages**`).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))).catch(() => null)
            return
                  
        }
        else {
            message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0])
            .then().catch(e => {
            message.channel.send(e.message)
            })
            .then(messages => message.channel.send(`**Succesfully deleted ${messages.size - 1} messages**`).then(msg => msg.delete({ timeout: 5000 }))).catch(() => null)
            return
        }
        
    },
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `message.channel.bulkDelete(<amount>, true)`

Comment: No, they didn’t put true

Answer (score 2):

[bulkDelete](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/TextChannel?scrollTo=bulkDelete) can take a 2nd argument called filterOld.
As the name suggests, that makes discord.js ignore all messages older than 14 days.

Example:

`message.channel.bulkDelete(notPinned, true)`

`message.channel.bulkDelete(args[0], true)`